Selenium Tests Fail to Start Chrome in Jenkins
When running Selenium tests in Jenkins, Chrome fails to start properly, resulting in an error message indicating that Chrome exited normally, but ChromeDriver assumed it has crashed. When I run the script in the terminal, it executes fine with out any error.
Error message:
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Shell Command:
python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
pytest -v -s --html=Reports/report.html testCases

Error:
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
service = Service('./chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver')

@pytest.fixture()
def setup1(browser):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-pipe')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    browser_instance = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, service=service)
    base_url = ReadConfig.getApplicationURL()
    number = ReadConfig.getNumber()
    otp = ReadConfig.getOTP()
    browser_instance.get(base_url)
    homepage = HomePage(browser_instance)
    homepage.setNumber(number)
    homepage.clickLogin()
    homepage.setOtp(otp)
    homepage.clickOtp()
    yield browser_instance
    browser_instance.quit()

